# How to maintain Global variable across threads in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, global-variables

I have the following structure in my project.

file1.py

```
def run_tasks_threads():
    task1 = threading.Thread(target=do_task_1)
    task1.start()
    ...

from file2 import DO_OR_NOT

def do_task_1():
    while True:
        print DO_OR_NOT
        if DO_OR_NOT:
            # do something
```

file2.py

```
DO_OR_NOT = True

def function1:
    global DO_OR_NOT
    # modify DO_OR_NOT
```

`run_tasks_threads` is called from yet another file. And as in this code, it **starts `task1` as a new thread.**

**My problem is that modification of `DO_OR_NOT` from `function1` is not getting reflected in `task1()`(new thread)!**

Note: This is actually a part of my Django server.
`function1` gets called multiple times.

Comment: Have you tried using events? they are very appropriate for this issues

Comment: @Jalo, No. Can you please provide some links?

Comment: @Jalo Do you mean to use `signals`?

Comment: Nope, I mean threading.Event() class... However, are you calling the files from different process? Or is there a parent process that calls file1. If they are in different processes, the problem is more complicated

Comment: As I said, it's a Django server. `function()` is called from a `view function`. and `run_tasks_threads` is called when from url.py (when server process it's 1st request)

Comment: Take a look at my answer and tell me if it is suitable for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [threading.Event()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#event-objects) class provides you an interface for setting, clearing and getting boolean flags between threads.

In the file1.py, an event variable has to be passed to the function that creates the thread, and then to the target function:

```
def run_tasks_threads(my_event):
    task1 = threading.Thread(target=do_task_1, args=(my_event,)
    task1.start()

def do_task_1(my_event):
    while True:
        print my_event.is_set()
        if my_event.is_set():
            # do something
```

Finally, in the main script that calls the previous functions, the event has to be updated every time you call the `function1`:

```
def main():
    #Create an instance of the event class
    my_event = threading.Event()
    file1.run_tasks_threads(my_event)
    while True
        global DO_OR_NOT
        #Get the bool value
        file2.function1()
        #Update the event flag depending on the boolean value
        if DO_OR_NOT:
            my_event.set()
        else:
            my_event.clear()
```

Comment: It's tough to have a `main` script in my project.

Comment: @JithinPavithran you should use this code in the script that calls file1 and file2... If these calls are part of the same parent process, there should be a common namespace for them. As I said before, if file1 and file2 are called from different processes, you can't use my solution and the problem gets more complicated

Comment: @JithinPavithran what I am trying to ask is if url.py is called apart from the script that contains the view function, or  if they belong to a common parent script

Comment: all of it should finally go to a thread. But it's all django core(& default) stuff which I don't want to modify (nor I know them).

Comment: @JithinPavithran while they are in different processes, it will be meaningless to use multithreading and global variables, as global namespace gets out of this scope. You should  use OS resources to share variables between these different processes for achieving your goal

Comment: @JithinPavithran from **Dive Into Python book**: _global namespace - specific to the current module. If the module has defined a variable, function, or class called x, Python will use that and stop searching. _